# How do I add rows to sub table?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I created 2 tables, one is parent and one is child. I added some rows to the parent table, and when I try to update any key via sub table it gives me the error

I have this homework where I need to create tables customer, foreign customer and domestic customer. Because this is a homework I can't use an attribute customer_type so I created 3 tables. The code is below:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
    customerID int not null,
    name varchar(80) not null)

CREATE TABLE ForeignCustomer(
    foreignCustomerID int not null,
    fcName varchar(80) not null,
    currency int not null,
    city varchar(50) not null,
    state varchar(50) not null,
    zipcode varchar(50) not null)

ALTER TABLE Customer
ADD PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID,name) 


ALTER TABLE ForeignCustomer
ADD FOREIGN KEY (foreignCustomerID,fcName) REFERENCES Customer(customerID,name)
```

While I have Customer table like this:

```
customerID = 1, name = 'james'
customerID = 2, name = 'rosie'
```

Until here, nothing gives any errors. Everything works fine.

I try to do this:

```
insert into ForeignCustomer(foreignCustomerID, fcName, currency, city, state, zipcode)
values(1, 'king', 500, 'new york', 'new york', '10030')
```

But I get the error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK__ForeignCustomer__48CFD27E". The conflict occurred in database
>   "BicycleCompany", table "dbo.Customer". The statement has been
>   terminated.

Shouldn't I be able to update the primary key like this? Or are you not allowed to do an operation similar to this kind?

Comment: @Larnu thanks i was just gonna edit the code

Comment: But in your table `Customer` you don't have a customer `'king'` (with the `ID` `1`), you have the customers `'james'` and `'rosie'`; of which the first has the `ID` of `1`. `1,'king'` <> `1,'james'` and so your foreign key reference fails.

Comment: Can't I update the key from 'james' to 'king' ? I thought I could.

Comment: Yes, @halid but you would need to perform the `UPDATE` on the table `Customer` first, and then perform the `INSERT`. Personally I suggest against duplicating the client's name in the table `ForeignCustomer`; as you won't be able to change the customer's name once it's inserted into `ForeignCustomer`.

Comment: @Larnu thanks I didn't know that, I thought I could overwrite the value by inserting into the ForeignCustomer table.

Comment: Foreign keys exists for referential integrity it would be counter intuitive (and incorrect) to suppose inserting or updating a child table would update the parent.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the foreign key must exist in the parent table, for your given example,

```
insert into ForeignCustomer(foreignCustomerID, fcName, currency, city, state, zipcode) values(1, 'james', 500, 'new york', 'new york', '10030')
```

Should work